# reorder columns based on value

Tags: oracle

is there any way to reorder columns in a table (or query) based on value.

for example, on every row, FacName should be first, NPI - 2nd, TIN - 3rd and Address - 4th.

thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you want to move data between columns strongly implies that the underlying data model is broken and needs to be normalized.  Fixing the data model would be much more appropriate than adding another layer of complexity to the system.

That being said, you should be able to do something like

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'FacilityName%' THEN column1
             WHEN column2 LIKE 'FacilityName%' THEN column2
             WHEN column3 LIKE 'FacilityName%' THEN column3
             WHEN column4 LIKE 'FacilityName%' THEN column4
             ELSE null
         END) column1,
       (CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'NPI%' THEN column1
             WHEN column2 LIKE 'NPI%' THEN column2
             WHEN column3 LIKE 'NPI%' THEN column3
             WHEN column4 LIKE 'NPI%' THEN column4
             ELSE null
         END) column2,
       (CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'TIN%' THEN column1
             WHEN column2 LIKE 'TIN%' THEN column2
             WHEN column3 LIKE 'TIN%' THEN column3
             WHEN column4 LIKE 'TIN%' THEN column4
             ELSE null
         END) column3,
       (CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'Address%' THEN column1
             WHEN column2 LIKE 'Address%' THEN column2
             WHEN column3 LIKE 'Address%' THEN column3
             WHEN column4 LIKE 'Address%' THEN column4
             ELSE null
         END) column4
  FROM( <<your query>> )
```

Comment: first of all, thank you so much!!!! and i totally agree, this is a horrible looking set but this is not really data, these are column headers. this is a step in an automation and i'm trying to get all the possible combination of the fields and then make insert queries out of them. But you're right, it's a mess, i just can't come up with a better way

Answer (score 2):

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from (
  select * from (
    select 
      n, str, row_number() over (partition by n order by 
      decode(substr(str,1,3),'Fac',1,'NPI',2,'TIN',3,'Add',4)) cn 
    from (
      select * from (select t.*, rownum n from t)
      unpivot (str for cn in (col1 as 0, col2 as 0, col3 as 0, col4 as 0))
    )
  )
  pivot (min(str) for cn in (1 as col1, 2 as col2, 3 as col3, 4 as col4))
)
order by n
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b742/1)

Comment: спасибо))))) but i chose the answer before i saw yours so i upvoted yours instead. is that OK?

Comment: порадовал, спасибо))))))))))